# Why do time travellers in the Terminator universe prefer nighttime arrivals?

Tags: the-terminator-series

In the first three movies of the Terminator franchise all the time-travellers arrived at night.  The fourth movie had no time-travellers.  The fifth movie was an altered re-telling of the first movie's story, again with nighttime arrivals.  Only in the sixth film, *Terminator: Dark Fate*, did we have a daytime arrival, that of the Rev-9; the human sent back still arrived at night.  Even the television show *Terminator: The Sarah Connor Chronicles* kept the faith with only nighttime arrivals.  There's no explanation for this preference in the movies or TV shows.

**Is there an explanation offered in any scripts or novelizations?**

Comment: Less people around to ask silly questions like "*who are you, where did you just appear from and **why are you naked***"?

Comment: @Valorum Yah, the Terminator 3 nighttime arrival in the desert made the most sense in that regard.  On the other hand, chopping a spherical hole out of a major city, complete with wind and million volt electrical arcs, is going to attract attention even at night.

Comment: Something something solar activity.

Comment: @Valorum One could sell it as a [Big Entrance](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BigEntrance) on a standard Californian nudist beach.

Comment: so the lightning spark special effects show up on camera better?

Comment: I can't find anything in any of the novelisations or tie-in novels. Gonna check the comics next but I'm not expecting to find much. I think it's just a case of tail-wag-dog. They arrived at night in the first film, hence they keep doing it in subsequent films